# Converting R factor levels that are strings into their numerical rank (emphasis: converting strings to numerical rank)

Tags: r, string, numbers, r-factor

Let's say I have an example factor in `R` consisting of text strings:

```
foofac <- factor(rep(c("Laudato","Si","Signore"),2),levels = c("Laudato","Si","Signore"))

foofac
[1] Laudato Si  Signore Laudato Si  Signore
Levels: Laudato Si Signore
```

Although the levels are strings themselves, they still have numerical rank.

This can be seen from `str(foofac)`:

```
Factor w/ 3 levels "Laudato","Si",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Question: **How do I succinctly capture that rank?** (in this case, 1 2 3 1 2 3)?

Put differently, **how do I create an output object (e.g., vector) that "converts" (or perhaps captures) my factor's ranked levels into the form of numerals**?

- So `Laudato Si Signore Laudato Si Signore` becomes `1 2 3 1 2 3`.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

```
foofac <- factor(rep(c("Laudato","Si","Signore"),2),levels = c("Laudato","Si","Signore"))

as.numeric(foofac)
```

### Output

```
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: Oy! Duhh! See, I got too fancy and tried `as.numeric(levels(foofac))`, which introduced a bunch of `NA`s. Well, like my momma always taught me: [K.I.S.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)  Thanks, mate!